# How Spring team is looking forward to this new release of Velocity ? Velocity Engine 2.1 Released [Sunday, 31 March 2019]

Tags: java, spring, freemarker, velocity

We have utilized Velocity 1.7 in our project for view part in MVC web application. But recently Velocity released 2.1 version. And currently I was trying to integrate FreeMarker there over Velocity. But came to know this latest release of Velocity 2.1

So, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-velocity

Says, "
As of Spring Framework 4.3, Velocity support has been deprecated due to six years without active maintenance of the Apache Velocity project. We recommend Spring’s FreeMarker support instead, or Thymeleaf which comes with Spring support itself."

Seems like Spring didn't liked inactive progress of this Velocity earlier.

So, wanted to know, how Spring community looks forward to this latest release of Velocity 2.1

Can someone from spring.io type us here your thoughts, Many thanks...!!

Comment: This would be better asked on Spring forums rather than SO

Comment: @AdamMichalik : Makes total sense.

Comment: The same can be said for XmlBeans and the response from the Spring team is that droppped support won't be introduced. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22403. If support is wanted it is on the project itself to add that support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same has happend with [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Supported was dropped but later a new version of XMLBeans has been released.

[A request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22403) for re-adding support for XMLBeans was requested but was denied. The answer to this request also mentions Velocity. The request was denied by Juergen Hoeller (the lead for Spring Framework development)

> Like with Velocity, we do not intend to reintroduce XMLBeans support out of the box anymore. If such integration is still desirable, our former marshalling adapter classes should be a fine starting point and could easily be part of the XMLBeans project itself, co-maintained along with its own further evolution.

So in short, the policy is to not re-add support for framework that where previously supported. That is now tasked for the framework (Velocity, XMLBeans) itself instead of Spring.